# MIME-type for tgz

Tags: gzip, mime-types, tar

I found several defintions for a gzipped tarbar (`.tgz` or `.tar.gz`), which is the correct one, is there one?

- application/x-gtar ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats), [Some bugtracker](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-33787))
- application/x-tar-gz ([Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-tgz-as-upload-mime-type), [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.common_types))

Didn't found a match in the [official list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Comment: Officially, use the `application/gzip`, since the tar.gz file is a GZipped Tarball file.  https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/gzip